# how do parameters of methods in python work?

Tags: python, sql, function, class, methods

Why doesn't this `insertfun()` method work with the test case in the main? Am I using the parameters wrong or creating the object wrong in main with the parameters I've given?

```py
class Connection
     def insertfunc(self, ID, REQUESTER, PAGE, DESCRIPTION, NEXT_STEPS, EFFORT, PRIORITY,
                    STATUS, REQ_DATE):
         insert = "INSERT into dash (REQUESTER, PAGE, DESCRIPTION, NEXT_STEPS, EFFORT, PRIORITY, STATUS, REQ_DATE)"
         self.ID = ID
         self.REQUESTER = REQUESTER
         self.PAGE = PAGE
         self.DESCRIPTION = DESCRIPTION
         self.NEXT_STEPS = NEXT_STEPS
         self.EFFORT = EFFORT
         self.PRIORITY = PRIORITY
         self.STATUS = STATUS
         self.REQ_DATE = REQ_DATE
         print("row inserted")
         return insert

if __name__ == "__main__":
     Connection.insertfunc(51,'Michael', 'New Tab', 'TEST', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '7/21/2021')
```

Comment: What result do you expect? Your method returns a string, and sets a bunch of attributes that you never seem to use. What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and what exactly doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: You never instantiate a `Connection` object...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not instantiating the object first. This is what you meant:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Connection()
    c.insertfunc(51,'Michael', 'New Tab', 'TEST', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '7/21/2021')
```